# how to organize html image sources for future content changes

Tags: html, css

I have a certain number of images into the html, and each one is accompanied with some text and/or transitions. Each set of img and whatever else (text, video, etc...) is inside a div to allow and simplify positioning. Also, each image is numbered as in a magazine or a book. Lets say for the shake of argument that there are 30 pages.

Then from the art dept, I receive a new page, which will be the fourth page, displacing the following ones one page further. Also, for organization porpouses, the img files also are renamed (i.e. img-20-jpeg now is img-21-jpeg)

Im looking for a way to avoid renaming manually classes of each div, img, paragraph, both in html and css.

I have tried to ignore actual numbers in img sources and refer the css styling to each "page" by nth-child selector.
Also, I have tried to relate each set of text, effects, etc... to it's inmediate "page" parent with ~.

so far, i have succeded only in epic headaches.

```
<div class="page">
  <img class="page" src="photo/img.001.jpeg" alt="1">
  <p class="text-page-1">
     some text
  </p>
</div>
<img class="page" src="photo/img.002.jpeg" alt="2">
<img class="page" src="photo/img.003.jpeg" alt="3">
<div class="page">
  <img class="page" src="photo/img.004.jpeg" alt="4">
  <video class= "video-page-4" src="video/4.mov" controls playsinline loop></video>
</div>
<div class="page">
  <img class="page" src="photo/img.005.jpeg" alt="5">
  <p class="text-page-5">
     some other text
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: **1.** You said "Each set of img and whatever else (text, video, etc...) is inside a div...", but there are 2 images that are *not* inside a div. **2.** You haven't explained why the numbering is important. From what you've said so far, I don't see a reason for the numbers. If the art dept sends a new image, just insert it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! For 1. the images without divs do not have anything else (text, video, etc...), and I try to avoid unnecessary divs. Still, the Class=page is both at divs or imgs in order to make a page for each img.  For 2. The problem is that I am the underdog here. Art Dept exports their whole document, which is the reason why the numbering changes. Im planning on blackmailing them to change the method, but thats not a matter for this forum! Thank you again for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple ideas.

1. avoid numbering; use comments to keep track. also change the hard-coded classes like `text-page-1` to get a paragraph inside of class page: `.page p` or `.page > p`.

```
<!--page 1-->
<div class="page">
    <img src="photo/img.001.jpeg" alt="1">
    <p>
        some text
    </p>
</div>
<!--page 2-->
<div class="page">
    <img src="photo/img.0045.jpeg" alt="1">
    <p>
        some text
    </p>
</div>
```

2. use old-school numbering. start at 10 and go up by 10, or even 100. 
   that way you can do inserts without renumbering everything.

```
<div class="page">
    <img src="photo/img.10.jpeg" alt="1"> <!--start at 10.-->
    <p class="text-page-10"> <!--use class only if necessary-->
        some text
    </p>
</div>
<!--can insert a new page here using numbers 11-19.-->
<div class="page">
    <img src="photo/img.20.jpeg" alt="1">
    <p class="text-page-20">
        some text
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The numbering format comes from the exported files I receive, which always start from 001 onwards. But you gave me a good idea for the new pages. Also, the classes for paragraphs need to be targeted separately, as each one will be placed at different places, and with different alignment, justification.... Still, I think they may be targeted as "parapgraphs after (or inside) page number nth" than "text-page-x". Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
    <!--page 1--> 
    <div class="page">
        <img class="page" src="photo/images/img1.jpeg" alt="1">
        <p class="text-page-1">some text</p>
    </div>
    <!--page 2-->
    <div class="page">
        <img class="page" src="photo/images/img2.jpeg" alt="2">
        <img class="page" src="photo/images/img3.jpeg" alt="3">
    </div>
    <!--page 3-->
    <div class="page">
        <img class="page" src="photo/images/img4.jpeg" alt="4">
        <video class= "video-page-4" src="video/4.mov" controls playsinline loop></video>
    </div>
    <!--page 4-->
    <div class="page">
        <img class="page" src="photo/images/img5.jpeg" alt="5">
        <p class="text-page-5">some other text</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I dont see nothing new here after what user Wazz already replied. Also, the intended method is to maintain the html when the data in, lets say, img2 is now in the new archive named img3. I think your method only adds more manual work instead of reducing it. Thanks anyway, and please clarify if im missing your point